# Where is the place for respectful questions and comments on candidates to moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Where is the place for respectful questions and comments on candidates to moderator *during these 5 days*?

Comment: Just ask them in chat, that seems to be the easiest way. If the candidate hasn't been in the chat room recently you can't ping them, but any chat mod (name in blue) can help you with that.

Comment: Some folks have very public profiles, and with a bit of google I'm sure you could even get a hold of their personal email.

Answer (score 8):

As Mad Scientist said in a comment, you can pose questions to people [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar). However, be aware that not all candidates visit the chat room, and so it may be impossible to get their attention that way.

You can also leave a comment somewhere where it'll get the candidate's attention, asking them to join you in the chat room.

Comment: @Mad Scientist Thank you both.